# Http Post request using tcpClient using proxy

Tags: c#, post, proxy, tcpclient

II have to send http post data to a website throw a proxy and receive the server response. 
For example, I want to send the request

```
request=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\ntest_check=Hello");
```

In my site, I check if the post data is well sended. In this case, I return "Ok".
First, I writte something like this:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(host, port);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
stream.Flush();
while ((count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            response.Append(encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, count));
```

The response is empty. What wrong?

After that will worked, I want to send the request via TcpCLient of a proxy server. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using HTTP Protocol, you should use the HttpWebRequest class which does support setting a proxy with the WebProxy class.

Comment: Ok for the proxy question, but what do you think for the first question?

Comment: I would have to re-read up on the HTTP protocol, but your first code snippet wouldn't even be needed if you use the HttpWebRequest and set the Method to POST.  There could be a lot of reasons why a response wasn't returned.  I would recommend Fiddler or after sending the request with the HttpWebRequest, you would get the HttpWebResponse and you can check the headers for the status code to see if you are having issues elsewhere.  That space between POST and the protocol version seems a miss, but again, I would have to check the specification.